# Google Cloud ML, extend previous run of hyperparameter tuning

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am running hyper parameter tuning using Google Cloud ML. I am wondering if it is possible to benefit from (possibly partial) previous runs.

One application would be :

1. I launch an hyperparameter tuning job
2. I stop it because I want to change the type of cluster I am using
3. I want to restart my hypertune job on a new cluster, but I want to benefit from previous runs I already paid for.

or another application :

1. I launch an hypertune campain
2. I want to extend the number of trials afterwards, without starting from scratch
3. and then for instance, I want remove one degree of liberty (e.g. training_rate), focusing on other parameters

Basically, what I need is "how can I have a checkpoint for hypertune ?"

Thx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is an interesting workflow -- Its not exactly possible with the current set of APIs, so its something we'll need to consider in future planning.

However, I wonder if there are some workarounds that can pan out to approximate your intended workflow, right now.

1. Start with higher number of trials - given you can cancel a job, but not extend one.
2. Finish a training job early based on some external input - eg. once you've arrived at a fixed training_rate, you could record that in a file in GCS, and mark subsequent trials with different training rate as infeasible, so those trials end fast.

To go further, eg. launch another job (to add runs, or change scale tier), you could potentially try using the same output directory, and this time lookup previous results for a given set of hyperparameters with an objective metric (you'll need to record them somewhere where you can look them up -- eg. create gcs files to track the trial runs), so the particular trial completes early, and training moves on to the next trial. Essentially rolling your own "checkpoint for hypertune".

As I mentioned, all of these are workarounds, and exploratory thoughts on what might be possible from your end with current capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to tweak around :-)